# Image handling in android, pinch zoom in browser

Tags: android, image

Hi All
I am working on an android app where i need to implement an image zooming functionality(zoom will work by moving fingers apart and bringing them together will zoom out the image).This is just like the way iphone does.
Could anyone please let me know is this possible?,Does Android provide any inbuilt support in SDK for doing this?.Is there any kind of tutorial for doing this?.

Android default browser supports pinch zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya pinch zoom  is possible in android  but after 2.2 version,and also many hardware doesn't support this feature.

but if you want to implement you can take look here..
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

i think it will help you.